# useSelecter not update when action dispatched

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I would like to make spinner effect each times api fetching so i dispatch show spinner action in axios interceptor:

```
axiosService.interceptors.request.use(
  (conf) => {
    store.dispatch(onThunkShowSpinner());
    return conf;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

onThunkShowSpinner:

```
export const onThunkShowSpinner = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: SHOW_SPINNER });
};
```

at spinner state i got log show everytimes api fetching as expected:

```
const spinnerReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SHOW_SPINNER:
      console.log('show');
      return {
        show: true,
      };
    case HIDE_SPINNER:
      return {
        show: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

but show value did not update that make me so confusing now

```
function Spinner() {
  const { show } = useSelector((state) => state.spinnerReducer);
  const classes = useStyles();
  console.log(show);

  return (
    <Backdrop className={classes.backdrop} open={show}>
      <CircularProgress color="inherit" />
    </Backdrop>
  );
}
```

Comment: For sake of curiosity, why don't use dispatch as the direct action creator instead of thunk? and could you check out what happened inside redux devtool?

Comment: show value does not change in redux devtool :(

Comment: does the console have "show" from the reducer?

Comment: yes, console does log it

Comment: Did you double-check the procedure of adding items to the redux root state? I'm afraid I can provide more help.